# Is the space $\mathbb{R}_+\times S\times S$ linear?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

The space $\mathbb{C}$  (or even $\mathbb{R}^2$), which is a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$, can be obtained from the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}_+\times S$ by gluing to the point the layer $0 \times S$, where $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,+\infty)$ and $S$ is the unit circle of the complex plane (this is just a polar decomposition of complex numbers). What about the space obtained from $\mathbb{R}_+\times S\times S$ by gluing to a point the layer $0 \times S \times S$? Is that (3-dimensional) space linear (over $\mathbb{R}$)? Can we define a linear structure on that space using the linear structure on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: well if you don't require anything from the linear structure you can always find a bijection between whatever it is and $\Bbb R^3$ (or $\Bbb R^n$ for any $n \ge 1$) and pull back the linear structure from there.

Comment: Thanks! I think that what you wanted to say is that in some cases the linear structure may be artificial in some sense. So which conditions should be satisfied and what should we require from the linear structure in order to  say that the linear structure is ''natural''?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there would be a natural structure of a real vector space on the set $X$ that one obtains from $\mathbf R_+\times S\times S$ by indentifying the subset $\{0\}\times S\times S$ to a point, then the topological quotient space $X$ should at least be homeomorphic to the topological space $\mathbf R^3$. Unfortunately, $X$ is not even locally homeomorphic to $\mathbf R^3$. Indeed, let  $x_0$ be the point of $X$ corresponding to the subset we have contracted to a point. The link of $X$ at $x_0$, i.e., the boundary of a metric ball centered at $x_0$, for some suitable metric on $X$, is homeomorphic to the torus $S\times S$, whereas the link of any point of $\mathbf R^3$ is homeomorphic to the $2$-sphere $S^2$. Since the torus and the $2$-sphere are not homeomorphic, there is no natural structure of a real vector space on $X$.